# R - Function to combine index from vector and raster stack layers

Tags: r, function, stack, raster

I am trying to write an efficient script to calibrate hundreds of Landsat 8 images. At a certain point of the calibration steps, I need to apply some coefficients in each layer of a raster stack.

This is one sample stack:

```
fn <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
s  <- stack(fn, fn)
```

And these are sample coefficients:

```
mult <- c(0.0003342, 0.0005534) 
add  <- c(0.1, 0.2)
```

What I need to is to apply each index of the coefficients to the correspondent index of the stack layer, like in this example:

```
s[[1]] <- (s[[1]] * mult[1]) + add[1]
s[[2]] <- (s[[2]] * mult[2]) + add[2]
```

This is my poor attempt, which obviously does not work:

```
cal.fun <- function(x) { 
x <- (x * mult) + add 
}

s.cal <- calc(s, cal.fun, progress='text')
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Many thanks.

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with a raster or can you abstract that away and give a simplier reproducable example with sample input and expected output?

Comment: @A.Webb it is definitely related to raster objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**raster** is a phenomenally well-constructed package and you can simply do:

```
s2 <- s * mult + add
```

For quick visual confirmation that that vectorized call "just works", do something like this:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(rasterVis)
grid.arrange(levelplot(s), levelplot(s2), nrow=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Or further reassure yourself by doing `(s2-add)/s`!

Comment: I did some testing with a couple of big files and what you proposed was waaaaaaay faster than what I had on mind!

Comment: I was wondering: the multiplication is really simple, but is there any way to add a progress bar to this operation?

Comment: @ThiagoV.dosSantos Not that I know of.